Filtering http requests activities by OpenTelemetry in Azure Monitor
Library name and version
Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.AspNetCore 1.2.0
Query/Question
Hi,
Prologue
We use built-in .NET Core authentication/authorization with multiple schemes for different OpenID providers. Each time I request my API, first call makes requests to all OpenID providers' ".well-known" endpoints. So far it's ok. But it creates request and dependency traces for each operation in Application Insights. That traces are totally irrelevant for us and we would like to filter them. I followed your guidelines and did something like this:
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor();
builder.Services.Configure<HttpClientTraceInstrumentationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FilterHttpRequestMessage = req =>
        !req.RequestUri.ToString().Contains(".well-known");
});

Problems

When I do that it still creates "request" telemetry types, even though the condition above is correct. (picture below)
UseAzureMonitor has it's own configured Http instrumentation, which is overridden when I do that.

Questions

How I can fully filter them out? Give me some suggestions please.
Overriding Http instrumentation seems to me like a violation in the opposite to UseAzureMonitor, as it has its own purpose. I would see that those filtering as additive, instead of replacement. Am I doing something wrong or for know it's the only way to do that?
I created ActivityFilteringProcessor with setting up IsAllDataRequested = false but it does not totally filter out the traces.


BR
Environment

Windows 10

Visual Studio 2022 17.10.1

.NET SDK:
Version:           8.0.300
Commit:            326f6e68b2
Workload version:  8.0.300-manifests.4e5ea2d8
MSBuild version:   17.10.4+10fbfbf2e

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.19045
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\



Ok, it didn't take long, but I finally managed it.
internal class OpenIdFilteringProcessor : BaseProcessor<Activity>
{
    public override void OnEnd(Activity data)
    {
        if (data.Kind == ActivityKind.Client && data.GetTagItem("url.full") is string url && url.Contains(".well-known"))
        {
            data.ActivityTraceFlags &= ~ActivityTraceFlags.Recorded;
        }
    }
}

(...)

builder.Services.ConfigureOpenTelemetryTracerProvider(builder => builder.AddProcessor<OpenIdFilteringProcessor>());
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor();


https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-contrib/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http#filter-httpclient-api You can use the Filter capability provided by the HttpClient instrumentation itself.

I wrote that this solution didn't help me in the way I want.

I have the same problem. The UseAzureMonitor() overrides my own HttpClient instrumentation filter. I think this is a bug in UseAzureMonitor(). Something like this was discussed in https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/issues/1562 but the issue was closed without the resolution.
